# ZeroMQ failing to communicate between two Docker containers

Tags: python, docker, zeromq, configuration-files, pyzmq

I'm trying to set up a toy example of Docker networking with ZeroMQ in macOS, where the `serverd.py` sends a message to the `clientd.py` and the client simply displays it using PUSH/PULL. If I run them outside of the container they work fine, but I'm having trouble getting them to communicate when running within separate containers. It seems like my `clientd.py` cannot connect to the container name despite them being within the same bridge network. I tried replacing the hostname with the assigned ip address for `serverd_dev_1`, but this doesn't work either.

Here's my setup:

1. I created a new network with `docker network create -d bridge mynet`. Here is the output from `docker network inpsect mynet`:

   ```
   {
       "Name": "mynet",
       "Id": "cec7f8037c0ef173d9a9a66065bb46cb6a631fea1c0636876ccfe5a792f92412",
       "Created": "2017-08-19T09:52:44.8034344Z",
       "Scope": "local",
       "Driver": "bridge",
       "EnableIPv6": false,
       "IPAM": {
           "Driver": "default",
           "Options": {},
           "Config": [
               {
                   "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                   "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
               }
           ]
       },
       "Internal": false,
       "Attachable": false,
       "Ingress": false,
       "ConfigFrom": {
           "Network": ""
       },
       "ConfigOnly": false,
       "Containers": {
           "5fa8dc2f8059d675dfd3dc4f2e50265be99361cd8a8f2730eb273772c0148742": {
               "Name": "serverd_dev_1",
               "EndpointID": "3a62e82b1b34d5c08f2a9f340ff93aebd65c0f3dfde70e354819befe21422d0b",
               "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
               "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
               "IPv6Address": ""
           },
           "ec1e5f8c525ca8297611e02bcd3a64198fda3a07ce8ed82c0c4298609ba0357f": {
               "Name": "clientd_dev_1",
               "EndpointID": "a8ce6f178a225cb2d39ac0009e16c39abdd2dae02a65ba5fd073b7900f059bb8",
               "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
               "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
               "IPv6Address": ""
           }
       },
       "Options": {},
       "Labels": {}
   }
   ```
2. I created `serverd.py` and `clientd.py` like this and put them in separate folders along with their Dockerfiles and docker-compose.yml:

serverd.py:

```
import zmq
import time

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
address = "tcp://127.0.0.1:5557"
socket.bind(address)
print("Sending to {}...".format(address))
while True:
    message = socket.send_string("Got it!")
    print("Sent message")
    time.sleep(1)
```

clientd.py:

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
address = "tcp://serverd_dev_1:5557"
socket.connect(address)
print("Listening to {}...".format(address))
while True:
    message = socket.recv_string()
    print("Client got message! {}".format(message))
```

I have two Dockerfiles and docker-compose.yml:

Dockerfile for serverd.py:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN mkdir src
ADD serverd.py /src/
RUN pip install pyzmq
WORKDIR /src/
EXPOSE 5557
```

Dockerfile for clientd.py:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN mkdir src
ADD clientd.py /src/
RUN pip install pyzmq
WORKDIR /src/
EXPOSE 5557
```

docker-compose.yml for serverd.py:

```
dev:
  build: .
  command: ["python", "-u", "./serverd.py"]
  net: mynet
```

docker-compose for clientd.py:

```
dev:
  build: .
  command: ["python", "-u", "./clientd.py"]
  net: mynet
```

3. `serverd.py` starts up as expected with `docker-compose up`:

`Sending to tcp://127.0.0.1:5557...`

4. `clientd.py` won't start up like this due to it not finding the hostname `tcp://serverd_dev_1:5557`.

   ```
   Attaching to countd_dev_1
   dev_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
   dev_1  |   File "./countd.py", line 6, in <module>
   dev_1  |     socket.connect(address)
   dev_1  |   File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 528, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.connect (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:5971)
   dev_1  |   File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 25, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:10014)
   dev_1  | zmq.error.ZMQError: Invalid argument
   ```
5. If I replace the URI `tcp://serverd_dev_1:5557` with `tcp://172.18.0.2:5557` it does not crash anymore, but it is simply idling without receiving any of the messages from the server. Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not entirely sure what exactly. I feel like I have been following the Docker documentation as closely as possible, and would very much be grateful if you had any ideas.

Comment: My suspect is a docker-isolation of devices. Would you mind to set the target addresses in an IPv4-absolute-format on the **`.bind()`**-side, as `address = "tcp://172.18.0.2:5557"` not to rely on any DNS-resolution and using it also as the respective `.connect()`-target on the client-side? **`EXPOSE`** seems just to mediate port-management between host 0/S resources management and docker-abstraction used for isolation, so the internal ( inside-docker-container ) code ought use the properly setup `<transport-class>:\\address:port#` on their own view of the world ( from an insider perspective ).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your primary problem is that you have configured your server with the address `tcp://127.0.0.1:5557`.  Because it's bound to localhost (`127.0.0.1`), that socket isn't going to be visible to anything outside of that container.  So the first thing you need to fix is the server bind address.  Consider:

```
address = "tcp://0.0.0.0:5557"
```

A second problem is that you're using the name `serverd_dev_1` in the client, but it's not clear this would actually be the name of your serverd container(that would depend on the directory names in use when you run `docker-compose up`).

Naming is easier to manage with a single docker-compose.yaml file.  For example, I set things up like this:

```
version: "2"

services:
  serverd:
    build: serverd
    command: ["python", "-u", "./serverd.py"]
    environment:
      SERVER_LISTEN_URI: tcp://0.0.0.0:5557

  clientd:
    build: clientd
    command: ["python", "-u", "./clientd.py"]
    environment:
      SERVER_CONNECT_URI: tcp://serverd:5557
```

This will launch both containers in a dedicated network (because this is what docker-compose does by default), so you don't need to explicitly create or reference `mynet`.

As you can probably infer from the above, I modified your code to get the ZMQ uri from an environment variable, because this made it easier to experiment.  You can find the above docker-compose.yaml and the modified code at:

- https://github.com/larsks/so-example-jimmyc

**Update**

In case you really want/need to have two separate `docker-compose.yaml` files, I've updated the example to include per-service files.  These examples use the `alias` option to provide a name by which the client can contact the server, regardless of your local directory layout:

```
version: "2"

services:
  serverd:
    build: .
    command: ["python", "-u", "./serverd.py"]
    environment:
      SERVER_LISTEN_URI: tcp://0.0.0.0:5557
    networks:
      mynet:
        aliases:
          - serverd

networks:
  mynet:
    external: True
```

This configuration requires that you create `mynet` before bringing up the containers.

Comment: With all due respect, the O/P has posted the code-under-test right from the begining ( **item 2** above, both the **serverd.py** and **clientd.py** ). The code ( with having properly fixed the `<transport-class>`, DNS / hostname resolution and `IPv4-address:port#` ) works, so the hypothesis about a bug inside the ZeroMQ-part fails to be correct.

Comment: @larsks Thank you for such a thorough answer! I was confused on two parts: I assumed since examples using port forwarding to the host machine used localhost, so would using docker network. Secondly, I thought Containers ->Name in `docker network inspect mynet` was the name to use as host name. Your suggestion to combine the docker-compose.yml made everything a lot better as well. Thanks for taking your time!

Comment: @user3666197 it looks like the person complaining about bugs has pulled his comments, so I'm going to remove mine as well since they're not really relevant to the answer...

Comment: @larsks Amazing effort! It truly helped me on many fronts as a Docker newbie.  It is people like you that make stackoverflow such an amazing resource.